# CSS to change the size of a TextField in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, textfield

I know I can do

```
TextField tempField = new TextField();    
tempField.setMinSize(500,500);
```

within JavaFX but I have about 45 text fields to change so I'd like to change them all at once by setting CSS on the scene.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out

```
.text-field{
    -fx-min-width: 50;
    -fx-min-height: 50;
}
```